# Dark Overlay that Closes on Click?

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am very new to programming and I am trying to setup a dark overlay over a whole page of my site, except some content with z-index. But the issue is the following, I need to be able to close/disable the dark overlay once I press on the overlay, I have not been able to find a way to do it on Google or on Stackoverflow. The only way I have seen it done is by using a button but that won't work in my instance, I just want to be able to disable the dark overlay when you click on any part of the dark overlay.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: You will need [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), possibly [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) too.

Comment: could you post your `HTML` and `JavaScript`, that should really help us to help you back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript (and jQuery) for that:

Event listener for click and then hide overlay

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
This is the content below the overlay
</div>
<div id="overlay">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for, this will help me immensely on the way to get a better grasp.